# How to update a value within a column with another value- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a static table that I want to replace a particular value with a string. In other words, in my table, I want to replace the value dog in the type_1 column with 'primate'.

**Here is my table:**

```
t_id|type_1|count
1, dog, 22
2, cat, 55
3, bird, 12
```

**Here is my expected output:**

```
t_id|type_1|count
1, primate, 22
2, cat, 55
3, bird, 12
```

As you can see, I just want to replace the value dog with the value primate.

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.type_1, 'dog', 'primate')
  FROM table_1 t
  where t.type_1 = 'dog' and t.t_id='1'
```

I am new to oracle sql so the syntax is a bit confusing to me. Any ideas or suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a query, use a `case` expression:

```
select t.t_id,
       (case when t.type_1 = 'dog' then 'primate' else t.type_1 end) as type_1,
       t.count
from table_1 t;
```

If you want to change the value *in the table* (i.e. permanently), use `update`:

```
update table_1
    set type_1 = 'primate'
    where type_1 = 'dog';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like update.

This is what you have:

```
SQL> select * from animal;

      T_ID TYPE_1            CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 dog                22
         2 cat                55
         3 bird               12
```

Change "dog" to "primate":

```
SQL> update animal set type_1 = 'primate' where type_1 = 'dog';

1 row updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from animal;

      T_ID TYPE_1            CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 primate            22
         2 cat                55
         3 bird               12

SQL>
```

---

Or, if you just need a `select` statement, then `case` might do:

```
SQL> select t_id,
  2         case when type_1 = 'dog' then 'primate'
  3              else type_1
  4         end as type,
  5         cnt
  6  from animal;

      T_ID TYPE              CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 primate            22
         2 cat                55
         3 bird               12

SQL>
```